# ng-include is not working even with single quotes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, include, frontend

I am following this tutorial: http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/level/4/section/1/video/1

The only thing I did different was add a folder in my file structure. 
Even if I remove it and put the 'product-title.html' in the root with my index.html it doesnt work.

```
<h3 ng-include="'includes/product-title.html'"></h3>
```

This seems pretty straight forward, am I doing something wrong?

The code in the product-title.html is:

```
{{product.name | uppercase}}
<em class="pull-right">{{product.price | currency}}</em>
```

I am using the following dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.4.7",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.5"
  }
```

[image: file structure]

Comment: You have to put the full path not the relative path

Comment: I tried that too. no luck.. ng-include="'/includes/product-title.html'"

Comment: could you show your directory structure?

Comment: Also is it the error productController not found?

Comment: added the structure. The error I have is: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/includes/product-title.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: It worked when I ran it on my localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error you mentioned

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/includes/product-title.html.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http,
>   data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

You can't click the html file and run it directly, have to run it at a local server such as Apache

Comment: Yeah once I saw that error I knew what it was. Feel kinda dumb for asking now. I used IIS and got it working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Mac, you can do this:

1. Open Terminal and go to your Angular project folder
2. Type `php -S localhost:3000` (or another port, whatever)
3. On browser, access this address and... done!